# How to run multiple testcases in ruby using test:unit

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testunit

I have used rake but rake combines one or more test suite as per my knowledge.

I need some method where I can do

```
ruby testsuite.rb 1 2 3 5 8 9
```

so here the desired testcases in the testsuite should run.

I am able to run a single test case using

```
ruby testsuite.rb --name testcase_name
```

Comment: Please put a little effort into making your question readable.

Answer (score 1):

`ruby testsuite.rb --name` accepts regular expression and can match more than one test. For example to run test1 and test2 in test_suite.rb, you can do this:

```
ruby test_suite.rb --name "/test1|test2/"
```

Comment: thanks for ur answer.. but is there any method where we can simply write the testcase name and then get the execution done like

ruby test_suite.rb -- name 1 12 23 45 65

so in this the respective testcases run accordingly as mentioned above. As i dont have to make it complex or hard . The user have to just write the serial number of the testcase and it will run.And user can give any number of testcases .

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. You want to be able to run test case within the test suite by number (1st, 3rd...)?